# Making the camera travel through a hole in a letter

Tags: after-effects, camera, animation, post-production, special-effects

I need to know if there is a way for a camera to travel through a hole in a letter or something flashy like a portal in After Effects CC.

Comment: You need to explain your question a bit more. If you mean can you move a camera through a transparent part of a layer, then yes, it can.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one idea for the effect, which you can even do in Premiere:

1. Get a live-action camera shot where the camera is slowly trucking forward.
2. In post-production, create a title that has at least one letter with a hole in it (A, B, D, O, P, Q, etc.).
3. Lay the title over the top of the trucking-in shot.
4. Animate the scale and position of the title over several seconds, so that the title gets larger and larger, and the hole stretches towards the edges of the screen. Since this is happening while the camera in the live-action scene is trucking forward, it will appear that the title is hovering in the air within the live-action scene.
5. When the hole in the letter is larger than the screen (because of the increasing scale), the animation is done.  At that point, it will appear as though the camera has traveled "through" the hole in the title, and is continuing to move forward.  (You can cut the title from the timeline at that point.)

Comment: if you can, make the letters 3D so as you pass through the hole you can see the depth of the character... but I would do the exact same thing BrettFromLA just said.

Comment: Yeah, 3D letters would look cool!